# Performing a POST request and showing the response into an <iFrame>

Tags: angular, rest, iframe, http-post

I'm working an Angular app that will be shown within an `<iFrame src="http://myBackendApi/auth">` where the URL in `src` tag should point to a `/POST` endpoint that will call my backend to see if the user in the `RequestBody` is eligible to the app or not and then respond with the frontend URL (eg: `http://localhost:4200/myApp)`.

Is there a way to perform that /POST call and show the server response in the iFrame ?

Comment: when component loads, inside ngOnInit() you can perform /Post request to api, and as per response from server you can pass value to iframe src.

Comment: Can you share your use-case more in details ?

Comment: Actually I'm only working on the application that will be shown on that `iframe`.
The one who's embedding mine I'm not sure it's developed with Angular and I can't edit it :(

Comment: @Ghaseen (load)="onLoad()" iframe has this load event, Can You able to use it or not ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44268351/how-to-post-traditional-form-into-iframe-within-an-angular-4-app is this working for you ?